# How are these definite integrals equal?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I don't understand how the following is achieved.

The solutions manual has
$$\pi\int_{-2}^2[(5-y^2)^2 - 1] \,dy = 2\pi\int_0^2[y^4 - 10y^2 + 24] \,dy.$$

The parts I don't understand are

1. How they changed the limits of integration from $-2$ and $2$ to $0$ and $2$.
2. How they got the constant $2$ out front.

Could someone explain this?

Comment: You don't need to to do this though, you'll get the same answer, but yes this comes from the even properties of the function under the integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a>0$ and $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in[-a,a]$, then
$$
\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx=2\int_0^a f(x)\,dx.
$$

It is well-known fact. If not, one can easily derive it from the definition of integral.

Comment: Oh okay, I never learned that. I was thinking it had something to do with the additive interval property. Thank you!

Comment: @Xerif917 You are welcome. BTW: if a function is odd, then integral over $[-a,a]$ equals 0.